# VueJs SPA execute function on click button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, components, emit

I need to run refreshMailList function from mail-list tag catching the click event from mail-list component.

I have this vue instance with this component:

```
Vue.component('mail-list', {
  props: ['inboxmail'],
  template:
  `
  <div>
    <h4>{{inboxmail}}</h4>
    <button>Refresh</button>
  </div>
  `
  });


//Creating the Vue object.
let options = {
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    pollingId: null,
    inbox: ''
  },

  created: function() {
    this.refreshMailList()
  },
methods:{
    refreshMailList: function(){
      fetch('/inbox')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(aJson => {
        this.inbox = aJson;
      })
    },

  } //end methods
} //end options

//ViewModel (vm)
let vm = new Vue(options);
```

And I have this index.html:

```
      <div id="app">
        <mail-list v-bind:inboxmail="inbox" @refresh='refreshMailList'></mail-list>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to emit the event from inside the mail-list component.

Try this snippet:

```
 Vue.component('mail-list', {
  props: ['inboxmail'],
  methods: {
    refresh: function() {
      this.$emit('refresh');
    },
  },
  template:
  `
  <div>
    <h4>{{inboxmail}}</h4>
    <button @click="refresh">Refresh</button>
  </div>
  `
  });
```